# Vue JS Module not found (datepicker)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am pretty new to vue.js - I only started using it today and naturally I have run into an error I cannot seem to resolve.

I am using the v-md-date-range-picker module: 
 (https://ly525.github.io/material-vue-daterange-picker/#quick-start.

The instructions tell me to do the following:

### 1

> npm install --save v-md-date-range-picker

### 2

```
<template>
  <v-md-date-range-picker></v-md-date-range-picker>
</template>
```

#### 3

```
<script>
import Vue from 'vue';
import VMdDateRangePicker from "v-md-date-range-picker";
import "v-md-date-range-picker/dist/v-md-date-range-picker.css";

Vue.use(VMdDateRangePicker);
</script>
```

So, I ran the command in terminal in my project folder, added the 2 bit of code to my HelloWorld.vue page and then added the code from step 3 into the `main.js`.

When I have a look in my `package.json` file, I see:

```
"dependencies": {
  "core-js": "^2.6.5",
  "v-md-date-range-picker": "^2.6.0",
  "vue": "^2.6.10"
},
```

However, I get the error:

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'v-md-date-range-picker/dist/v-md-date-range-picker.css' in '/Users/James/Documents/projects/vue-test/src'

am I missing something blatantly obvious here?

#### Edit:

I tried the response in the comments below which did not work.

On the main page of the module, I followed the instructions. However, going through the pages I found the same instructions with some extra text:

> I assume that you have a working bundler setup e.g. generated by the vue-cli thats capable of loading SASS stylesheets and Vue.js SFC (Single File Components).

I am going to go out on a limb here and say I do not have a working bundler. I went into the node_modules folder, found that module and looked inside. There was no dist folder. Just .scss files etc..

So, I assume that I somehow need to build this project first.

How do I do that?

I thought running it in the browser would have done this on the fly but it clearly has not.

### Edit 2:

After some googling around I found the command:

```
$ npm run build.
```

Which gives me this error:

> This dependency is not found, To install it, you can run: npm install --save v-md-date-range-picker/dist/v-md-date-range-picker.css

So, I run that command and then I get the error:

> Could not install from "v-md-date-range-picker/dist/v-md-date-range-picker.css" as it does not contain a package.json file.

Comment: It is a component, you should specify it in the [components section](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html) and use that as the tag name.

Comment: Hi @MatJ Thanks for the reply. It is my understanding that this is a module, not correct? I followed the instructions from the officials docs. Have I missed something?

Comment: Edit: I just took it out of the main.js and added the imports etc to the component vue file and that throw a bunch more errors.

Comment: ah thanks, that link didnt show up as a link (edited?). Anyway thanks I shall go through it an have a look.

Comment: @MatJ Please see edit to original post

Comment: If you are getting that error, a build will most likely not succeed. Anyways, the proper command to build a VueJs app is `npm run build`.

Comment: @RichardMcFriendOluwamuyiwa Thanks, I just made another edit that will see the result of that, you were right. The build will not succeed. What the hell am I doing wrong here, It cant be this hard to use a datepicker module, surely?

Comment: From that error (which was obvious even without the error anyways since you say the module doesn't contain a dist folder), I will add an edit to my answer.

Comment: `It cant be this hard to use a datepicker module`, if it is written correctly, that is. You are using an alpha stage module, it might not work as intended. Remove that css import and try. I don't think you need that, it should be embedded in the component itself as a scoped style.

Comment: If you are just trying to learn vue.js, go use some well written controls. There are hell lot of controls out there and you found this alpha stage module only? Interesting...!

Comment: @MatJ Ah, I never considered it would even be the package file itself. I removed that css line and it worked fine. Thank you. I didnt know about other controls, I just searched for "date range picker for vue" or something and went with the first one I saw. Thank you again your solution worked. If you want to add it as an answer I will accept it :)

Comment: Cool, no problem. When you are learning something new, its always better to start with established modules, other wise you won't understand if the error is something in what you did or in the module itself and can make you frustrated with the very thing you are trying to learn. Anyways, Happy to know that it worked.

Comment: @MatJ - yeah, I just realised that. I clicked dates and console logged the values. They do not match what I checked, months and dates are wrong fml. Do you know any good places for controls?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you can find this in the `webpack.base.conf.js` inside the build folder. If not add it.

```
module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'], // Note that the order is very important
      },
```

Run `npm install style-loader css-loader --save` before adding it to the file if it isn't there.

To Address your question

Run the command: `npm install sass-loader --save`

Then add an import for every SCSS file in the module.

> This is not the most optimal solution, but that package looks broken to me and this is merely a workaround.

I will take time to try out the library myself and try to provide a fix for it.

Comment: I do not have a build folder. I only seem to have node_modules, public and src

Comment: Looks like the file path is wrong. You can dig into the `node_modules` folder and see what file you should actually be referencing.

Answer (score 0):

Create **v-md-date-range-picker.css** in  **v-md-date-range-picker/dist/** and copy css  from 
[md-date-range-picker.min.css](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/md-date-range-picker@0.8.4/dist/md-date-range-picker.min.css)

and  refresh your page. For some reason css file is not being created when we install md-date-range-picker.min